# How to accept comma-delimited list to build tags for model? 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm switching off of acts_as_taggable_on because of limited flexibility for my current application. Instead, I'm building my tags from scratch as their own model. However, I already miss the "@model.tag_list" method for forms, that would split up comma-delimited user input and make individual tags. My "taggable" model is a video, and I'm curious how to write a method that can essentially act like the "tag_list"?

Example:

```
<%= form_for @video do %>
  <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
  ....
```

Given the input: `"one, two, three"`
Would build three Tags as children of the @video.

```
@video.tags.each do |tag|
  puts tag.name
end

=> one
two
three
```

**EDIT**

I'd really like this in the Tag model, to keep form cluttering my controller. Maybe as a custom attribute? Maybe the Video model would make more sense? I know how to make a custom method to *return* custom data, but not assign it. Some research points me this way (not yet tested)

video.rb

```
def tag_list=value
  value.split(',').each do |tag|
    self.tags.build(:name => tag).save
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like my example code ended up working

**video.rb**

```
def tag_list=value
  value.split(',').each do |tag|
    self.tags.build(:name => tag).save
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Also need to add to get it to work in a form:

```
def tag_list
  self.tags.join(',')
end
```

Comment: This did not work for me - I get "tags is invalid" error when I post the form. Can you post your entire code that worked? Thanks.

Comment: @Anand that was 4 years ago... But it sounds like you have a validation on `tag` that isn't being met.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave tag_list as an attribute on Video, then in your create you could just have something like:

```
def create
  @video = Video.new(params[:video])
  if @video.save
    params[:video][:tag_list].split(',').each do |tag|
      @video.tags.create_by_name(tag)
    end
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah but is there a way to move that out to the model? I'd like to keep that out of my controller. Especially since I also plan on having other kinds of tags. So there will be tag_list, actor_list, director_list, etc...