# create multiple records from a comma separated entry in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've looked at these two SO discussions yet it's not working for me

1) [Creating multiple records at once from comma seperated IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689204/creating-multiple-records-at-once-from-comma-seperated-ids)

2) [How to accept comma-delimited list to build tags for model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611475/how-to-accept-comma-delimited-list-to-build-tags-for-model)

I am trying to take a single string from a form and create multiple active record entries being separated by commas

form:

```
<%= form_for @tag, html: {:class => "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>               
            <fieldset>
              <div class="form-group">
                <%= f.label :tagname, "Tag Name", :class => "col-lg-3 control-label" %>     
                <%= f.text_field :tagname, :class => "form-control" %>                       
              </div>      

              <div class="form-group">                      
                  <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
              </div>
                  <%= link_to 'Back', tags_path %> |
                  <%= link_to 'Home', :userroot %>   
            </fieldset>
<% end %>
```

controller:

```
def create
@tag = params[:tagname].split(/,\s*/)
@tag.each do |t|
  newtag = Tag.new(:tagname => t)
  newtag.save
end
redirect_to tags_path
end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError in TagsController#create 

undefined method `split' for nil:NilClass

Request 
Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RwjDJ9WQD6nJ51AymbSBubcmDbzDNTYWot0nP1FPV04=",
 "tag"=>{"tagname"=>"a new tag, two tag, three tag"},
 "commit"=>"Create Tag"}
```

Comment: Have you checked your params? Your comma delimited string is probably under `params[:tag][:tagname]`

Comment: i knew it had to be something that simple... thanks. please post as an answer so i can give you credit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your params? Your comma delimited string is probably under

```
params[:tag][:tagname]
```

Be sure to check if the string is empty anyways, you can't expect perfect behaviour from the user.

GL & HF.